# Using Open instruction in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible use the "Open" instruction in VBA to work with shared text files?
For example, 2 people sending at same time a command to write in the file.

Comment: Not really.  Text files aren't meant to be used this way.  The problem is that there are no locking mechanisms to prevent editing conflicts.  Use something like a database or Git to accomplish this.

Comment: If the pattern is open-write-close, with the file not being held open by one user, you can write a loop which tries to write to the file, and if it fails, waits a short time and tries again.

Comment: A way to do this with text files would require something like a client server structure, where the server is the only one allowed to write into the text file and the clients would communicate with the server and request their changes. The server application then needs to keep track on the data integrity and accept or decline the change requests from the clients to avoid conflicts.